# How to scrape website without API and format into a mobile app (iPhone, Android, etc.)?

Tags: android, ios, web-scraping

I am interested in obtaining data from a website and displaying it within a "native" mobile application instead of simply accessing it through the mobile device's browser, as the website is too cumbersome for use on a tiny mobile device and could be better accessed through a native application.  However, that website doesn't offer an API to access its functionality.  Is web scraping the best way to do this?  If so, what's the best way to accomplish that?  Are there any tools available to make this process easier?

Comment: tell us about the architecture of your application and how is it going to work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, scrape the data into an easy to use format such as CSV or JSON, then reuse that in your application. Have a look at [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [this webscraping library](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/).

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was looking for.  I want to know how to parse the data I want and then render it within a mobile app on android or iphone.

Comment: To parse the data use those linked libraries. How to render it depends on your mobile app.